# Is it possible to pin the bokeh toolbar so it doesn't scroll?

Tags: toolbar, bokeh

My bokeh figure has 60 plots arranged on a `gridplot` layout with 2 columns, 30 rows.  Even with a large screen, the typical user must scroll through the figure to see plots lower down on the page.

The toolbar, which is common to all plots, sits along the right edge (i.e., `toolbar_location='right'`).

Is it possible to "pin" the toolbar so that, as the user scrolls to the lower plots, the toolbar remains visible and accessible always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 0.13 (and upcoming 1.0) there is nothing built-in to accomplish this. It's possible you could embed your gridplot in a custom template, and add your own CSS rules to cause the toolbar to float, but I don't know how to advise you on the specifics of how to do that. Alternatively, you can set `merge_tools` to `False` when you call `gridplot`, which will cause every individual plot to have its own toolbar, instead of creating a single "merged toolbar".